# R/Plumber: Passing variable arguments to a function with

Tags: r, plumber

I'm experimenting with implementing an API using `plumber` with R. For the most part, this has worked brilliantly. I'm stuck, however, on being able to pass some unnamed, variable parameters to my function with ellipsis (`...`).

In the `plumber.R` file, I have a function definition like this:

```r
#* @get /make-team-leaderboard-live
#* @serializer contentType list(type='image/png')
function(
    stat = "avg",
    ...,
    flipOrder = FALSE,
)
```

The input is the stat for which to generate a graphic, following by additional variables to be included in the graphic.

From the client, I pass the additional variables as elements of a JSON array attached to the body of the request.

I unpack the additional argument in the body of my plumber function (I have verified through debugging that the additional arguments are, in fact, making it to the server). I then attempt to pass `additionalArgs` to the `...` parameter of the function, but this generates the error, "Can't subset columns with `additionalArgs`, `additionalArgs` must be numeric or character, not a list."

```r
additionalArgs <- list(...)

tbl <- df %>% make_graphic(
  stat = stat,
   ... = additionalArgs,
   flipOrder = flipOrder
)
```

Recognizing that `additionalArgs` contains and `elements` member, I've extracted the values from that member to form a character vector, but this too generates an error.

I've hit a dead end. I've searched for examples of API implementations with `plumber` that use variable parameters, but come up empty.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Why not have an explicit argument to your function that takes a list as a value?  Then you just call `make_graphic(stat=stat, additionalArgs = additionalArgs, flipOrder = flipOrder)`.

Comment: This turns out to be a good approach. Thanks for getting me thinking a different way. It required a change to the underlying API, but that was a small price to pay. Thanks again.